# How to access a variable defined inside a function, from outside that function

Tags: python, function, variables, scope

I am stuck on using variables defined in a previous function in another function. For example, I have this code:

```
def get_two_nums():
    ...
    ...
    op = ...
    num1 = ...
    num2 = ...
    answer = ...

def question():
    response = int(input("What is {} {} {}? ".format(num1, op, num2)))
    if response == answer:
        .....
```

How will I use the variables defined in the first function in the second function? Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you asking "how do I create variables in one function and have them be accessible in another function?"? Or are you asking "How do I evaluate the result of a mathematical equation where each component is stored as a string in its own separate variable?"?

Comment: possible dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/423379/1561176

Answer (score 6):

Variables are local to the functions; you need to `return` the relevant values you want to share to the caller and pass them to the next function that uses them. Like this:

```
def get_two_nums():
    ...
    # define the relevant variables
    return op, n1, n2, ans

def question(op, num1, num2, answer):
    ...
    # do something with the variables
```

Now you can call

```
question(*get_two_nums()) # unpack the tuple into the function parameters
```

or

```
op, n1, n2, ans = get_two_nums()
question(op, n1, n2, ans)
```

Comment: It returns the error: 'question () missing 3 required positional arguments: 'op', 'num2', and 'answer''

Comment: Whoops, sorry, you need to unpack the tuple. Will edit.

Answer (score 3):

Why not return a tuple?

```
def get_two_nums():
    ...
    ...
    op = ...
    num1 = ...
    num2 = ...
    answer = ...
    return op, num1, num2, answer

def question():
    op, num1, num2, answer = get_two_nums()
    response = int(input("What is {} {} {}? ".format(num1, op, num2)))
    if response == answer:
        # the rest of your logic here
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply pass them, because variables in  `get_two_nums` are defined only in  scope of `get_two_nums`function. 
So basically you have two options:

1. Return their values  as tuple into scope of another function as **@TimPietzcker** and **@Tgsmith61591** proposed.
2. Define variables  within  `get_two_nums` function as globals ( see [global statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-global_stmt), for more info) as in code snipper below:

   ```
   def get_two_nums():
       global num1
       num1 = 'value1'
       global num2
       num2 = 'value2'
       global num3
       num3 = 'value3'

   def question():
       # Call get_two_nums to set global variables for further using
       get_two_nums()
       response = int(input("What is {} {} {}? ".format(num1, num2, num3)))
       if response == answer:
           # Some code here ...
   ```

**WARNING:** Using global variables should be avoided, see [Why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil) to get better idea of what i am talking about ...

Comment: It should be mentioned that using `global` should be avoided in most circumstances. Once your program grows in size, `global` can make problems very hard to debug.

Comment: Surely you aren't advocating the use of `global`? This is a terrible practice.

Comment: Guys you are definitely right and i am totally agree with you, i've update answer with this warning. However using global also gives possibility to get behaviour about which OP asked ....